# How to deny delete/modify permission to a file?

Tags: security, permissions, file-permissions

I want to deny myself the ability to modify or delete an executable.

> When [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) asks you if you want to update:
>
> [image]
>
> and you choose **No** it spontaneously deletes itself as retribution:
>
> [image]

So I want to prevent myself from being able to `Delete` the executable; as punishment for their punishment.

I tried to **Deny** me `Write` permission (and deny it to **Everyone**, and **Administrators**):

[image]

Except, I can still Right-Click -> Delete the file...

How do I deny the delete/modify permission to a file?

Comment: Yeah, write access has nothing to do with delete permission.  This seems like a rather draconian way to solving this problem.

Comment: i'm surprised at a downvote. i would think being able to stop something from modifying your files would be a useful question.

Comment: @surfasb Write access very well may have nothing to do with delete. i only include things i've tried because some people get grump when i simply ask the question. And some people will give spiteful downvotes if i don't "show research effort".

Comment: Upvote solely because I find the question quite amusing.  Then I recalled painful times with the Adobe Flash installer and suddenly I feel less amused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, it is enough to have *one of*:

- "Delete" on the object, or
- "Delete child" on its parent

Therefore a file will only become undeletable if you *deny **both***.

Use `icacls` to edit the permissions:

- Deny "Delete" to the file:

  ```
  icacls Reflector.exe /deny Everyone:(D)
  ```
- Deny "Delete child" to the folder:

  ```
  icacls . /deny Everyone:(DC)
  ```

<sub>(Tested on Windows XP.)</sub>

Comment: Denying `Modify` permission also removes `Execute` permission; and i can still delete the file!

Comment: As I said, "You may also have to deny
"Delete items" on the folder"... Which too can be done with icacls.

Comment: On the downside that would deny the ability to delete other items in the folder. Given that it doesn't seem to be working, i presume it is not possible to deny the ability to delete a file - deletes must happen against folders, rather than files.

Comment: Edit your answer to indicate that it cannot be done, "But here are some alternatives that might be useful", and you'll get the accept.